# Weird behaviour in swiftUI+Combine when class --> struct

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In a youtube video tutorial one thing caught my eye. I've created a really simple project in order to reproduce it. I know that design of the code is not perfect, but I wonder why code behaves like this in this particular situation.

file #1

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.content).onAppear() {
            self.viewModel.subsribe()
        }
    }
}
```

file #2

```
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private let model = Model()
    @Published var content: String = ""
    var subscription: AnyCancellable?

    func subsribe() {
        subscription = model.getPublisher().sink { value in
            self.content = value
        }
    }
}
```

file #3

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class Model {

    func getPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        Just("Test")
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

In this code everything works as expected. But if in the file #3 `class Model` change to `struct Model` it stops work!
It's very strange, because... it seems not make any difference.

Hint #1
In fact we still get the message from publisher. But the view doesn't update it.

Hint #2
If we slightly change the code in file #2

```
private let publisher = Model().getPublisher()

func subsribe() {
    subscription = publisher.sink { value in
        self.content = value
    }
}
```

It works in both cases (with `class` and with `struct`)

Hint #3 (edited due to the comment of @Sweeper)
In file #2 if we take line of code `private let model = Model()` and move it to the bottom like this:

```
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

        @Published var content: String = ""
        var subscription: AnyCancellable?
        private let model = Model()

        func subsribe() {
            subscription = model.getPublisher().sink { value in
                self.content = value
            }
        }
    }
```

The code starts to work!!!
Can anybody else reproduce this behaviour?

P. S.
Link to the original video tutorial: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olZra64Wz9E&list=PLblCJtxTed706WzuhUwSmaR18BIlRHbZP)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I still see "Test" when I change to `struct`. Could it be because I'm using an older version of Xcode?

Comment: @Sweeper Unbelievable! I was shocked when I couldn't reproduce it either after your comment. So in panic I was trying to remember what did I change in code very before I posted it. I just made cosmetic refactoring. In file #2 I moved line "private let model = Model()" to the bottom. If the line is at the top, the code doesn't work with struct. If the line is at the bottom - it works! Everything is even worse, then I thought! I'm going to edit my post because of this new information. Thank you!

Comment: I still cannot reproduce... Changing the declaration order should not matter. Swift has been specifically designed so that properties can be initialised in any order.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I know!!! That's exactly why I so surprised. It's sad that you can't reproduce it. But I'm still experiencing the effect: when I change the order of declaration, the code changes its behaviour.

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: @Asperi Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29). I'm going to update it tomorrow. Will see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I can replicate on Xcode 11.4 - same thing happens if you remove the subscription/publisher and just do content = "Test"  in subscribe(). The order of where you init the Model seems to matter which is strange because it isn't related to the Published property at all. If you remove the Published attribute and add a didSet on the content property and put an objectWillChange.send() it works as expected - seems like a bug to me.